# Print array effective in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I want to print a int array in C++.

I know I can use a for loop to print it ,
But is there any `utils` for this? Like Arrays in Java .

Comment: There's no way to avoid a loop to print. It doesn't matter if you write the loop explicitly in your code, or use a function that hides the loop from you, there's still a loop somewhere. And not that it matters, terminal output is going to be the bottle-neck anyway.

Comment: Please provide [mre] for the way you know and want to improve and for the way it is done in java which you would like to use.

Comment: This might be one of the rare cases where tagging both languages, C++ and java, might be appropriate. But you are probably better off not trying. People here are allergic to more than one language tag...

Comment: And can you please try to be more specific? What is the problem you have with "a for loop"? How is it not "effective" enough? What are your requirements in regards to being "effective"? What is the base-line to which you compare effectiveness?

Comment: I think the feature you're looking for is "convenient", not "effective".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `Arrays.toString()` nor `Arrays.deepToString`
the most similar to

```
Arrays.asList(strArray).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

is the [ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)

```
int x[] = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 256};
std::copy(std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What C++ is missing is a default output operator for all data structures, so in a recent project I made operator<< for some of the standard types, and for the relevant data classes, so I could have that feature.

Some untested code

```
  template <typename dType>
  std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const std::vector<dType> &vec ) { 
     for (auto& it: vec)
         output << it;
     return output;            
  }
```

Only works if dType has defined an output operator, recursively.
dType should be a variadic parameter.

usage:

```
std::vector<int> intVec;
std::cout << intVec;
```

Comment: If you want this to be generic, why not define it for forward iterators rather than `std::vector`?

Comment: @Mansoor good point, I will consider that for my next project.